# Filtrar información con el método filter en Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**mi problema es el siguiente:**
tengo un arreglo que lo traigo vía `ajax`
y quisiera que ese arreglo pudiese filtrarse en mi lista pero, que cumpla una condición que es que el `id === otroArreglo.id` mis arreglos son estos:
este es mi arreglo principal que tiene como nombre logros

```
 "id": 1,
"specifiers": "",
"name": "1x2",
"status": 1,
"isFavorite": false,

   },

  {
"id": 10,
"specifiers": "",
"name": "Doble oportunidad",
"status": 1,
"isFavorite": false,


},
{
"id": 11,
"specifiers": "",
"name": "Apuesta sin empate",
"status": 1,
"isFavorite": false,


 },

   {
    "id": 12,
    "specifiers": "",
    "name": "FC Toronto sin apuesta",
    "status": 1,
    "isFavorite": false,

  },
```

y este es mi arreglo donde tengo los id que quiero mostrar

```
SeleccionLogrosExtra:[{id:1}, {id:11}]
```

lo que que quiero hacer es una propiedad computada que me devuelva el arreglo principal pero solo los del id del segundo arreglo
**quiero hacer algo como esto**

```
 GamesFilters: function () {
            let me=this;
            return logros.filter((e)=>{
                return e.id === me.SeleccionLogrosExtra.id;
            })
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Podría implementar una doble función [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) para saber que elementos retornar, siempre y cuando el id del elemento iterado `(e.id)` esté contenido en el `array` `seleccionLogrosExtra`

No es necesario utilizar una variable temporal para la referencia si usa funciones flecha *(arrow function)*

El nombre de las variables se modificaron, cuidado con ese detalle, hay que mantener la convención de nombres para métodos y variables.

```js
Vue.component('ejemplo-component', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      logros : [{
                "id": 1,
                "specifiers": "",
                "name": "1x2",
                "status": 1,
                "isFavorite": false
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "specifiers": "",
                "name": "Doble oportunidad",
                "status": 1,
                "isFavorite": false,
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "specifiers": "",
                "name": "Apuesta sin empate",
                "status": 1,
                "isFavorite": false,
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "specifiers": "",
                "name": "FC Toronto sin apuesta",
                "status": 1,
                "isFavorite": false,
            }
        ],
        seleccionLogrosExtra:[{id:1}, {id:11}]
    }
  },
  template:'Stack',
  computed: {
      gamesFilters: function () {
          return this.logros.filter((e)=>{
             // si existe el id en el array, el array retornado por filter debe ser mayor a 0
              return this.seleccionLogrosExtra.filter(el=> el.id === e.id).length > 0;
          })
      },
  },
  mounted() {
   console.log(this.gamesFilters);
  },
  template : '<p>El Resultado en Consola ;)</p>'
 
})

new Vue({ el: '#app' })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <ejemplo-component />
</div>
```